# Is it possible to get svn client debug output?

Tags: svn

I'm looking to enable extremely verbose logging output in the svn client specifically for the task of resolving botched merges.

The problem I'm facing currently is merging from trunk into my feature branch brings in no new changes, but a diff of the two HEADs reveals outstanding unmerged work.

Generally I'd think this means that the mergeinfo has been messed up, or there is some mergeinfo deeper in the project directory structure that is causing issues. However in this case I've cleaned all the mergeinfo properties and manually ensured the root of the feature branch's mergeinfo does not contain the revisions that are on the head of trunk which I'm attempting to merge in.

For this task and others I'm looking to be able to enable an SVN debug log which literally shows me stuff like:

- Attempting to merge in revision XXX from https:.... to working copy

  - Skipped, already merged in
- Attempting...

I was looking at recompiling the svn client with some sort of compile time flags to indicate logging verbosity but was not getting anywhere. Does anyone have any pointers on how to get more information from SVN Client? (command line, linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, no. --verbose exists but only for `svn status` and `svn pl` (possibly more, but not merge or update). I can definitely see the need for this, especially if you are messing around with mergeinfo.

It sounds like you know what your doing already but try to run `svn pl -v` to see the mergeinfo on the root node.

Also, I've noticed that svn 1.6.6 and earlier have problems with mergeinfo, specifically that it destroys it in certain cases. Upgrade to the latest (on ubuntu 10.04 I've checked out the source using svn, built it and then uninstalled the apt-get version).

Good luck.

Comment: Well, it was worth a shot ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You can get network debug output with `--config-option servers:global:neon-debug-mask=<level>` (see levels [here](http://happygiraffe.net/blog/2009/09/23/neon-debug-mask/)). This won't help with merges and other logic problems (*very* low level); just pointing it out for the sake of people who are googling for svn client debug output for network problems.

Comment: Note that it no longer works in subversion 1.8 and above since svn dropped support for the `libsvn_ra_neon` repository access module in favour of `libsvn_ra_serf`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. At the end of `~/.subversion/servers` file add:

```
neon-debug-mask = 511
```

Answer (score 0):

**might not directly be related to your question** but say you want to see what files:

```
svn up
```

looks at, i do this:

1. start `htop` in a shell
2. bring curser over the `svn up` process
3. hit `s` (for strace tracing)
4. hit `F4` (for filters) and add `open`
5. hit `F8` (for autoscrolling)

now i have a nice log output on 'svn' internals!

this is just an example but you can monitor any syscall(s) this way.